# Using a certain filter (made for GIMP 2.6) in GIMP 2.10.2

Tags: windows, gimp

I'm trying to use [this filter](http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?t=3153):
http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?t=3153

As far as I can see it was made for GIMP 2.6.

To use it with GIMP 2.10.2, I have downloaded the file "filltrans.scm" and put it into the folder "C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\GIMP\2.10\scripts\".

I have then started GIMP and tried to locate the filter, but I didn't see it under "Filters".

I have never used a custom filter. I'm not sure if I made a mistake by dropping it in the wrong place, or if I need to search somewhere else for this custom filter or if this .scm file is not compatible with GIMP 2.10.2.

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on this page:
http://gimpchat.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=3153&start=50

Actually, it's required to select in from the "Layers" menu.